# since Ubuntu 19.10 evince exits on mouse click or mark area events

Tags: mouse, 19.10, evince

since Ubuntu 19.10, `evince` exits on mouse click or mark area events

and hence it is impossible to copy text, even from my own PDF files, generated by PDF-LaTeX

LATER ADDITION>

1> my install is an upgrade from 19.04 , hence checksums of installed files are checked by the package manager subsytem

2> I removed (purged) `evince` and `evince-common` with `dpkg -P`, and then I reinstalled by `apt-get install --yes evince`, but the problem remained there

Comment: I do not understand why "user208066" is seen here as the author of the question, while I logged in as "prohlep".

Comment: 1) Did you verify the ISO you downloaded was not corrupted, even minutely, in transit? Please see https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . 2) If you did, then please uninstall/reinstall evince using Ubuntu Software. If the problem persists, please click [edit] and note you have done 1) and 2). Please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: 1> my intall is an upgrade from 19.04 , hence the checksums of the install files are checked by the package manager subsytem

2> I removed (purged) "evince" and "evince-common" with dpkg -P , and then I reinstalled by apt-get install --yes "evince" ------ but the problem remained there

Comment: TY for the follow through. Please move your details in the comment into the question by clicking [edit] so they're preserved; comments are not permanent, and are intentented for us to ask you for detail. What you have are essential troubleshooting facts and should be in the question. Also, I dunno why you were assigned a username different from what you signed in with; probably a glitch in a server. If you want to ask brighter minds than mine, ask about that in http://meta.stackexhange.com and add a link back to this question. TY.